# Xcode 4.2 project without storyboard

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I create a Tabbed Application in Xcode 4.2 without storyboarding. It did not create MainWindow.xib. Consequently, IB does not display the TabBar in its list of objects. So I cannot connect it to any outlets. In fact IB will not let me do anything to the Tab Bar in my app: I can't drag onto or move the region at all.

Questions:
How can I display the Tab Bar Controller in IB?
Is there another way of doing of connecting outlets to the Tab Bar Controller?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not display the window by default anymore.  If you really want to have it then you can create one, but it does not make a difference.

In response to the lack of a tab bar controller, it should be there.  Are you looking for it from a view.xib file?  I would recommend recreating the project if this persists, that may help.

Comment: I can live without the MainWindow.  

I see in the AppDelegate there is a TabBarController. But it does not appear in IB under File's Owner, so I cannot connect the TabBarController to an outlet.

Created a new Tabbed App projectwith same results: Tab or its controller does not appear in IB.

Comment: And it does not allow you to drag one in as an IB object?

Comment: no. The xibs for each tab merely show a black bar in place of the TabBar. I cannot select it. It seems like it is merely a placeholder. I cannot find a TabBar as an object in any xib file.

I'm gonna start again, but using a storyboard. I don't want to do this as it really limits my audience. But I don't know what else to try....